# Simple C# server to stream video over HTTP

Tags: c#, http, video, streaming

I am trying to create a simple console application in C #. I need to make a streaming video and it must be accessible directly from the browser.

I was reviewing the link [Streaming large video files .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862782/streaming-large-video-files-net), but it seems that this code is for asp.net

Another thing that i was trying, is TCPCliente, but I have problems when sending large files.

```
var fs = File.Open("../../video.mp4", FileMode.Open);

outHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
outHeaders.Add("Accept-Ranges", "0-" + fs.Length);

long size = fs.Length;
long length = size;
long startBytes = 0;
long endBytes = size - 1;

if (headers["Range"] != null)
{
    var msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HTTP/1.0 206 Partial Content" + "\n");
    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);

    var range = ParseRange(size, headers["Range"].ToString());

    startBytes = range.Start;
    endBytes = range.End;

    fs.Seek(startBytes, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    length = endBytes - startBytes + 1;
}
else
{
    var msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HTTP/1.0 200 OK" + "\n");
    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
}

outHeaders.Add("Content-Length", length);
outHeaders.Add("Content-Range", string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startBytes, endBytes, size));

SendHeader(stream, outHeaders);

int bytesRead = 0;
byte[] buf = new byte[client.SendBufferSize];
while (fs.Position <= endBytes && 
    (bytesRead = fs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
{
    stream.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    stream.Flush();
}

fs.Close();
```

the problem is in:

```
while (fs.Position <= endBytes && 
    (bytesRead = fs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
{
    stream.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    stream.Flush();
}
```

when fs.Position = 425984 I get the error:

```
No se controló System.IO.IOException
  HResult=-2146232800
  Message=No se pueden leer los datos de la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       en HttpServer.Program.Main(String[] args) en j:\HttpServer\HttpServer\Program.cs:línea 85
       en System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       en System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       en Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
       Source=System
       ErrorCode=10054
       NativeErrorCode=10054
       StackTrace:
            en System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
            en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       InnerException:
```

in line `stream.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);`

What can i do? 
thx

Comment: `I have problems when sending large file` What kind of probems do you have? `the problem is in:` Where? What? Why?

Comment: sorry, I edited the question with the error that gives me the code