# How to implement video file streaming in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stream, dispose

I want to implement simple video file streaming.
There is my API controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/VideoContent")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetVideoContent([FromUri] string fileName)
{
    if (fileName == null)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    if (Request.Headers.Range != null)
    {
        try
        {
            //using (FileStream fileStream = _videoFileProvider.GetFileStream(fileName))
            //{
                HttpResponseMessage partialResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
                FileStream fileStream = _videoFileProvider.GetFileStream(fileName);
                partialResponse.Content = new ByteRangeStreamContent(fileStream, Request.Headers.Range, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4"));
                return partialResponse;
            //}

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable);
}
```

This code is working, but as you see fileStream not disposed. I tried to use using block (commented lines), but this code doesn't work - in debug mode method run without exceptions, but browser shows response with 500 error code.

Where is my mistake? Why I am getting 500 Internal Server Error? How to correctly dispose file stream in my case?

Comment: [Maxad has a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862782/streaming-large-video-files-net) on closing the stream through a finally block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, what have you implemented for downloading content without disposing filestream is right.

As you have been using `HttpResponseMessage` for returning response which is automatically disposed by the framework itself after done with sending response to the client.

This has already been pointed by [MSFT guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751090/carlosfigueira) in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api#comment-24905710) of [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api)

If you looks at dispose method of [HttpResponseMessage in source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs),

```
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // The reason for this type to implement IDisposable is 
            //that it contains instances of types that implement
            // IDisposable (content). 
            if (disposing && !_disposed)
            {
                _disposed = true;
                if (_content != null)
                {
                    _content.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

You can see _`content` has been disposed which is of type `HttpContent` i.e. in your case, object of `ByteRangeStreamContent` set in the `Content` property of `HttpResponseMessage`.

Disposing [ByteRangeStreamContent](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/ByteRangeStreamContent.cs) object implemented in following way :

```
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Contract.Assert(_byteRangeContent != null);
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (!_disposed)
                {
                    _byteRangeContent.Dispose();
                    _content.Dispose();
                    _disposed = true;
                }
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

In above `Dispose` method of `ByteRangeStreamContent`, you can see that it is disposing itself and disposing _`content`(in your case `FileStream`) as well which is stream used for creating `ByteRangeStreamContent` object.

I strongly believe, your implementation without disposing filestream is correct as disposing starts in sequence when done with sending response to client.